# Unit testing, project with many database calls

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, stored-procedures

I have a question on unit testing. Currently I have a large project that calls many SP and does not get a return for most methods. Really it is a large wrapper for many SQL calls. There is not a lot of logic as it is all held in the SP it also has sections of in line sql.

I need to unit test this c# project but it is becoming clear that the unit test would be pointless as it would call many SP which all would be mocked. Am I worried I am thinking about this incorrectly.

My question is that has anyone had this problem and what did they do? Should I be doing database unit tests instead, any insight would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test should not touch a data access layer as that would be an integration test/system test.  What you can test is that your project in fact calls your data access layer.  Doing this will give you peace of mind that during refactors that clicking a button does always call the data access layer.

```
//Arrange
var dataAccessMock = new Mock<IDataAccessMock>();
dataAccessMock(da => da.ExecuteSomething());

IYourApplication app = new YourApplication(dataAccessMock);

//Act
app.SomeProcessThatCallsExecuteSomething("1234567890");

/Assert
dataAccessMock.Verify(dp=>da.ExecuteSomething(), Times.Once());
```

*note, in this example I am using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)*

After this is is tested to your liking you can focus on your integration test to verify your stored procedures are working as intended.  For this you will potentially need to do quite a bit of work to attach a database in a known state, run your stored procedures, and then revert or trash your database so the tests are repeatable.

Comment: `A unit test should not touch a data access layer as that would be an integration test/system test`.  That's not necessarily true.  If a stored procedure performs one unit of work, testing it is still a unit test.  It's an unfortunate architectural decision that unit-of-work business logic is in the database of course.

Comment: It all depends on your definition of a unit test, I believe a true unit test should run quickly and repeatable without any outside dependencies.  Anything that requires tear up/tear down in my opinion is an integration test (which you can use NUnit to run or your fav framework)

Answer (score 0):

You should split your testing strategy into integration testing and unit testing.

For integration testing you can rely on your existing database. You will typically write more high-level tests here and verify that your application interacts with your database correctly.

For unit testing you should only pick selected scenarios that actually make sense for mocking out. These are typically scenarios where a lot of business logic "sits on top" of your database logic and you want to verify that business logic.
Over time you can mock out more and more database calls, but for the beginning identify the critical spots.

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered one reason that business logic should generally go in the business, rather than data access, layer.  Certainly there are exceptions dictated by performance and sometimes security concerns, but they should remain exceptions.

Having said that, you can still develop a strategy to test your sprocs (though depending on how extensive they are, it may or may not be correct to call those tests "unit tests").

You can use a unit testing framework either way.

In the initialization section, restore a testing copy of the database to a known state, e.g. by loading it from a previously saved copy.

Then, execute unit tests that exercise the stored procedures.  Since the stored procedures generally do not return anything, your unit test code will have to select values from the database to check whether the expected changes were made or not.

It may be necessary, depending on possible interactions between stored procedures, to restore the database between each test, or between groups of related tests.

Answer (score 0):

Data / Persistence Layer could is the often most neglected code from a unit testing perspective (true unit testing using test doubles: mocks, stubs, fakes, etc.). If you are connecting to a database then you are integration testing. I find value in a) well architected data/persistence layers that as a side effect are easy to test (uses interfaces, good data access framework abstractedion, etc. and b) are actually unit and integration tested property.